# Text offset by 1 or 2 from its x in SVG

Tags: svg

I have `text` in my SVGs that is offset by 1 or sometimes 2 from its assigned `x`. The `text` is set at `x="6"` however, the text is at 7 or even 8.

Here is an SVG with all the letters of the alphabet and numerals 0 through 9 to show the offset. I just can not figure out why there is an offset. It gets worse when the text is in italics for some characters. Should I just subtract 1 from `x` to get the text where I want it? Is this normal behavior for the arial font in SVG?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
  viewBox="0 0 111 1088"
  width="111"
  height="1088"
  id="Alphabet_boxes"
>
  <title id="Alphabet_boxes_title">Alphabet boxes</title>
  <metadata id="Alphabet_boxes_metadata">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title>Alphabet boxes</dc:title>
        <dc:date>2020-05-19</dc:date>
        <dc:creator>
          <cc:Agent>
            <dc:title>Lady Aleena</dc:title>
          </cc:Agent>
        </dc:creator>
        <dc:language>en-US</dc:language>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <style id="Crossover_styles">
    path  { fill:none; stroke: #666666; stroke-width: 2; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round; }
    rect  { paint-order: stroke; stroke: #666666; stroke-width: 4; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linejoin: round; fill-opacity: 1; fill: #ffffff; }
    rect.inner { stroke: none; fill: #ccc; }
    text  { fill: #000000; font-family: arial, roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-anchor: start; dominant-baseline: middle; }
    g.normal_text { font-style: normal; }
    g.italic_text { font-style: italic; }
    g.bold_text   { font-weight: bold; }
    tspan { font-size: 90%; font-style: normal; }
  </style>
  <g id="Alphabet_boxes_chart" class="graph" transform="translate(5,5)">
    <title id="Alphabet_boxes_chart_title">Alphabet boxes</title>
    <g id="normal" class="normal_text">
      <g id="normal_A" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <title id="normal_A_title">A</title>
        <rect id="normal_A_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_A_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_A_text" x="6" y="14">A</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_B" transform="translate(0,30)">
        <title id="normal_B_title">B</title>
        <rect id="normal_B_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_B_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_B_text" x="6" y="14">B</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_C" transform="translate(0,60)">
        <title id="normal_C_title">C</title>
        <rect id="normal_C_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_C_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_C_text" x="6" y="14">C</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_D" transform="translate(0,90)">
        <title id="normal_D_title">D</title>
        <rect id="normal_D_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_D_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_D_text" x="6" y="14">D</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_E" transform="translate(0,120)">
        <title id="normal_E_title">E</title>
        <rect id="normal_E_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_E_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_E_text" x="6" y="14">E</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_F" transform="translate(0,150)">
        <title id="normal_F_title">F</title>
        <rect id="normal_F_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_F_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_F_text" x="6" y="14">F</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_G" transform="translate(0,180)">
        <title id="normal_G_title">G</title>
        <rect id="normal_G_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_G_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_G_text" x="6" y="14">G</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_H" transform="translate(0,210)">
        <title id="normal_H_title">H</title>
        <rect id="normal_H_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_H_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_H_text" x="6" y="14">H</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_I" transform="translate(0,240)">
        <title id="normal_I_title">I</title>
        <rect id="normal_I_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="15" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_I_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="7" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_I_text" x="6" y="14">I</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_J" transform="translate(0,270)">
        <title id="normal_J_title">J</title>
        <rect id="normal_J_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="19" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_J_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="11" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_J_text" x="6" y="14">J</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_K" transform="translate(0,300)">
        <title id="normal_K_title">K</title>
        <rect id="normal_K_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_K_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_K_text" x="6" y="14">K</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_L" transform="translate(0,330)">
        <title id="normal_L_title">L</title>
        <rect id="normal_L_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_L_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="12" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_L_text" x="6" y="14">L</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_M" transform="translate(0,360)">
        <title id="normal_M_title">M</title>
        <rect id="normal_M_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_M_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_M_text" x="6" y="14">M</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_N" transform="translate(0,390)">
        <title id="normal_N_title">N</title>
        <rect id="normal_N_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_N_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_N_text" x="6" y="14">N</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_O" transform="translate(0,420)">
        <title id="normal_O_title">O</title>
        <rect id="normal_O_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_O_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_O_text" x="6" y="14">O</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_P" transform="translate(0,450)">
        <title id="normal_P_title">P</title>
        <rect id="normal_P_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_P_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_P_text" x="6" y="14">P</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_Q" transform="translate(0,480)">
        <title id="normal_Q_title">Q</title>
        <rect id="normal_Q_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_Q_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_Q_text" x="6" y="14">Q</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_R" transform="translate(0,510)">
        <title id="normal_R_title">R</title>
        <rect id="normal_R_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_R_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_R_text" x="6" y="14">R</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_S" transform="translate(0,540)">
        <title id="normal_S_title">S</title>
        <rect id="normal_S_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_S_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_S_text" x="6" y="14">S</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_T" transform="translate(0,570)">
        <title id="normal_T_title">T</title>
        <rect id="normal_T_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_T_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_T_text" x="6" y="14">T</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_U" transform="translate(0,600)">
        <title id="normal_U_title">U</title>
        <rect id="normal_U_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_U_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_U_text" x="6" y="14">U</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_V" transform="translate(0,630)">
        <title id="normal_V_title">V</title>
        <rect id="normal_V_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_V_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_V_text" x="6" y="14">V</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_W" transform="translate(0,660)">
        <title id="normal_W_title">W</title>
        <rect id="normal_W_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="27" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_W_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="19" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_W_text" x="6" y="14">W</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_X" transform="translate(0,690)">
        <title id="normal_X_title">X</title>
        <rect id="normal_X_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_X_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_X_text" x="6" y="14">X</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_Y" transform="translate(0,720)">
        <title id="normal_Y_title">Y</title>
        <rect id="normal_Y_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_Y_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_Y_text" x="6" y="14">Y</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_Z" transform="translate(0,750)">
        <title id="normal_Z_title">Z</title>
        <rect id="normal_Z_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_Z_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_Z_text" x="6" y="14">Z</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_zero" transform="translate(0,780)">
        <title id="normal_zero_title">0</title>
        <rect id="normal_zero_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_zero_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_zero_text" x="6" y="14">0</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_one" transform="translate(0,810)">
        <title id="normal_one_title">1</title>
        <rect id="normal_one_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="17" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_one_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="9" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_one_text" x="6" y="14">1</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_two" transform="translate(0,840)">
        <title id="normal_two_title">2</title>
        <rect id="normal_two_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_two_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_two_text" x="6" y="14">2</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_three" transform="translate(0,870)">
        <title id="normal_three_title">3</title>
        <rect id="normal_three_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_three_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_three_text" x="6" y="14">3</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_four" transform="translate(0,900)">
        <title id="normal_four_title">4</title>
        <rect id="normal_four_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_four_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_four_text" x="6" y="14">4</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_five" transform="translate(0,930)">
        <title id="normal_five_title">5</title>
        <rect id="normal_five_box_2" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_five_box_1" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_five_text" x="6" y="14">5</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_six" transform="translate(0,960)">
        <title id="normal_six_title">6</title>
        <rect id="normal_six_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_six_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_six_text" x="6" y="14">6</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_seven" transform="translate(0,990)">
        <title id="normal_seven_title">7</title>
        <rect id="normal_seven_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_seven_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_seven_text" x="6" y="14">7</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_eight" transform="translate(0,1020)">
        <title id="normal_eight_title">8</title>
        <rect id="normal_eight_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_eight_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_eight_text" x="6" y="14">8</text>
      </g>
      <g id="normal_nine" transform="translate(0,1050)">
        <title id="normal_nine_title">9</title>
        <rect id="normal_nine_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="normal_nine_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="normal_nine_text" x="6" y="14">9</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="italic" transform="translate(37)" class="italic_text">
      <g id="italic_A" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <title id="italic_A_title">A</title>
        <rect id="italic_A_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_A_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_A_text" x="6" y="14">A</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_B" transform="translate(0,30)">
        <title id="italic_B_title">B</title>
        <rect id="italic_B_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_B_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_B_text" x="6" y="14">B</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_C" transform="translate(0,60)">
        <title id="italic_C_title">C</title>
        <rect id="italic_C_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_C_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_C_text" x="6" y="14">C</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_D" transform="translate(0,90)">
        <title id="italic_D_title">D</title>
        <rect id="italic_D_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_D_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_D_text" x="6" y="14">D</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_E" transform="translate(0,120)">
        <title id="italic_E_title">E</title>
        <rect id="italic_E_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_E_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_E_text" x="6" y="14">E</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_F" transform="translate(0,150)">
        <title id="italic_F_title">F</title>
        <rect id="italic_F_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_F_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_F_text" x="6" y="14">F</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_G" transform="translate(0,180)">
        <title id="italic_G_title">G</title>
        <rect id="italic_G_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_G_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_G_text" x="6" y="14">G</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_H" transform="translate(0,210)">
        <title id="italic_H_title">H</title>
        <rect id="italic_H_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_H_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="17" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_H_text" x="6" y="14">H</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_I" transform="translate(0,240)">
        <title id="italic_I_title">I</title>
        <rect id="italic_I_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="17" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_I_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="9" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_I_text" x="6" y="14">I</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_J" transform="translate(0,270)">
        <title id="italic_J_title">J</title>
        <rect id="italic_J_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_J_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_J_text" x="6" y="14">J</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_K" transform="translate(0,300)">
        <title id="italic_K_title">K</title>
        <rect id="italic_K_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_K_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_K_text" x="6" y="14">K</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_L" transform="translate(0,330)">
        <title id="italic_L_title">L</title>
        <rect id="italic_L_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_L_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_L_text" x="6" y="14">L</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_M" transform="translate(0,360)">
        <title id="italic_M_title">M</title>
        <rect id="italic_M_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="26" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_M_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="18" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_M_text" x="6" y="14">M</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_N" transform="translate(0,390)">
        <title id="italic_N_title">N</title>
        <rect id="italic_N_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_N_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="17" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_N_text" x="6" y="14">N</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_O" transform="translate(0,420)">
        <title id="italic_O_title">O</title>
        <rect id="italic_O_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_O_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_O_text" x="6" y="14">O</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_P" transform="translate(0,450)">
        <title id="italic_P_title">P</title>
        <rect id="italic_P_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_P_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_P_text" x="6" y="14">P</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_Q" transform="translate(0,480)">
        <title id="italic_Q_title">Q</title>
        <rect id="italic_Q_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_Q_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_Q_text" x="6" y="14">Q</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_R" transform="translate(0,510)">
        <title id="italic_R_title">R</title>
        <rect id="italic_R_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_R_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_R_text" x="6" y="14">R</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_S" transform="translate(0,540)">
        <title id="italic_S_title">S</title>
        <rect id="italic_S_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_S_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_S_text" x="6" y="14">S</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_T" transform="translate(0,570)">
        <title id="italic_T_title">T</title>
        <rect id="italic_T_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="22" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_T_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="14" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_T_text" x="6" y="14">T</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_U" transform="translate(0,600)">
        <title id="italic_U_title">U</title>
        <rect id="italic_U_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_U_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_U_text" x="6" y="14">U</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_V" transform="translate(0,630)">
        <title id="italic_V_title">V</title>
        <rect id="italic_V_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_V_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_V_text" x="6" y="14">V</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_W" transform="translate(0,660)">
        <title id="italic_W_title">W</title>
        <rect id="italic_W_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="27" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_W_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="19" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_W_text" x="6" y="14">W</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_X" transform="translate(0,690)">
        <title id="italic_X_title">X</title>
        <rect id="italic_X_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="26" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_X_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="18" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_X_text" x="6" y="14">X</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_Y" transform="translate(0,720)">
        <title id="italic_Y_title">Y</title>
        <rect id="italic_Y_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_Y_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="16" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_Y_text" x="6" y="14">Y</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_Z" transform="translate(0,750)">
        <title id="italic_Z_title">Z</title>
        <rect id="italic_Z_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_Z_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="15" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_Z_text" x="6" y="14">Z</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_zero" transform="translate(0,780)">
        <title id="italic_zero_title">0</title>
        <rect id="italic_zero_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_zero_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_zero_text" x="6" y="14">0</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_one" transform="translate(0,810)">
        <title id="italic_one_title">1</title>
        <rect id="italic_one_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="18" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_one_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="10" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_one_text" x="6" y="14">1</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_two" transform="translate(0,840)">
        <title id="italic_two_title">2</title>
        <rect id="italic_two_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_two_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_two_text" x="6" y="14">2</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_three" transform="translate(0,870)">
        <title id="italic_three_title">3</title>
        <rect id="italic_three_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_three_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_three_text" x="6" y="14">3</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_four" transform="translate(0,900)">
        <title id="italic_four_title">4</title>
        <rect id="italic_four_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_four_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_four_text" x="6" y="14">4</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_five" transform="translate(0,930)">
        <title id="italic_five_title">5</title>
        <rect id="italic_five_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_five_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_five_text" x="6" y="14">5</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_six" transform="translate(0,960)">
        <title id="italic_six_title">6</title>
        <rect id="italic_six_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_six_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_six_text" x="6" y="14">6</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_seven" transform="translate(0,990)">
        <title id="italic_seven_title">7</title>
        <rect id="italic_seven_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_seven_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_seven_text" x="6" y="14">7</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_eight" transform="translate(0,1020)">
        <title id="italic_eight_title">8</title>
        <rect id="italic_eight_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="21" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_eight_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="13" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_eight_text" x="6" y="14">8</text>
      </g>
      <g id="italic_nine" transform="translate(0,1050)">
        <title id="italic_nine_title">9</title>
        <rect id="italic_nine_box_1" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="28" />
        <rect id="italic_nine_box_2" x="4" y="4" width="12" height="20" class="inner" />
        <text id="italic_nine_text" x="6" y="14">9</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Change the attributes in the `svg` tag and add the `sodipodi:namedview` lines of the SVG to the following if you want to open it in Inkscape. The grid and guidelines are added so you can see the offset.

```xml
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
  xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
  version="1.1"
  sodipodi:docname="Alphabet_boxes_ink.svg"
  inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
  viewBox="0 0 111 1088"
  width="111"
  height="1088"
  id="Alphabet_boxes"
>
  <sodipodi:namedview
    pagecolor="#ffffff"
    bordercolor="#666666"
    borderopacity="1"
    objecttolerance="10"
    gridtolerance="10"
    guidetolerance="10"
    inkscape:pageopacity="0"
    inkscape:pageshadow="2"
    inkscape:window-width="1280"
    inkscape:window-height="979"
    id="namedview5209"
    showgrid="true"
    showguides="true"
    inkscape:guide-bbox="true"
    inkscape:zoom="1"
    inkscape:cx="52"
    inkscape:cy="1.1e+03"
    inkscape:window-x="0"
    inkscape:window-y="0"
    inkscape:window-maximized="1"
    inkscape:current-layer="Alphabet_boxes"
  >
    <inkscape:grid type="xygrid" id="grid5213" />
    <sodipodi:guide position="11,1088" orientation="1,0" id="guide5215" inkscape:locked="false" />
    <sodipodi:guide position="48,1088" orientation="1,0" id="guide5217" inkscape:locked="false" />
    <sodipodi:guide position="85,1088" orientation="1,0" id="guide5219" inkscape:locked="false" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
```

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand your question, By default text is anchored by the left bottom corner.  Please try adding  `text-anchor="middle"` to the text. Maybe this is what you need,

Comment: I want all the letters and numbers lined up at ```6```, and most are currently not sitting at ```6```. I was only using single characters for this example, however, I am using whole words in my rectangles. See https://fantasy.xecu.net/files/images/Fandom/Crossovers/Westerns_in_Crisis.svg where the ```T``` and ```Y``` in *The New Maverick* and *Young Maverick* are at 8 instead of 6. They are not lined up with the ```B``` and ```M``` in *Bret Maverick* and *Maverick* (1994).